# How can I apply a function to multiple Id's on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the script below to be used with various or multiple id's in different sections of the form, working independently from each other.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit *').prop( "disabled", true );
$('#submit').css('color','#ccc');

$("input:radio[class^='yes-']").click(function() {
$('#submit *').prop( "disabled", false );
$('#submit *').css('color','#000');
});
$("input:radio[class^='no-']").click(function() {
$('#submit *').prop( "disabled", true );
$('#submit input').prop( "checked", false );
$('#submit textarea').prop( "value", "");
$('#submit *').css('color','#ccc');
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/artboycat/dcpy5k6y/

Comment: Best of luck with that! …or did you mean to ask a question? Because, if you did, you forgot to show enough code (see the "[MCVE]" guidelines) to reproduce your problem, you forgot to properly indent your jQuery, you haven't explained where, or why, you got stuck, or what you need help with.

Comment: Use class, not IDs. Then use any relevant transversal method to target relevant inputs in specific field

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did explain. And also, I have a fiddle that outlined the basics. Next time I will include the html. Also, I thought I did properly indent it. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to resolve your query if I've understood it correctly. Please check the following. Please check the modifications made in HTML and JS code. Thanks :)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcpy5k6y/5/)

```
<div class="grps" id="grps1">

 <input type="radio" name="1" class="yes-1" value=1>yes 
 <input type="radio" name="1" class="no-1" value=2>no

<fieldset class="one" id="submit1">
  <legend>Event Type*</legend>
   <ul>
     <li>Please check event type that best describes your event</li>
     <li>This form must be submitted two weeks prior to event date</li>
   </ul>


<input type="radio" value="1" name="event-type-1" id="etype-1" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-1" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Meeting</label>   
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="event-type-2" id="etype-2" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-2" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Seminar</label>  
<br>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="event-type-3" id="etype-3" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-3" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Panel</label> 
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="4" name="event-type-4" id="etype-4" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-4" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Training</label>   
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="5" name="event-type-5" id="etype-5" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-5" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Symposium</label>  
<br>
<input type="radio" value="9" name="event-type-6" id="etype-9" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-9" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Other</label>
<div id="show-me"><TEXTAREA COLS="60" ROWS="4" name="other_item" id="etype-9" maxlength="80" size="25" class="input"></TEXTAREA></div>  

</fieldset>
</div>

 <BR clear="all">
<br>


<div class="grps" id="grps2">

 <input type="radio" name="1" class="yes-2" value=1>yes 
 <input type="radio" name="1" class="no-2" value=2>no

<fieldset class="one" id="submit2">
<legend>Event Type*</legend>
<ul>
<li>Please check event type that best describes your event</li>
<li>This form must be submitted two weeks prior to event date</li>
</ul>


<input type="radio" value="1" name="event-type-1" id="etype-1" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-1" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Meeting</label>   
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="event-type-2" id="etype-2" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-2" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Seminar</label>  
<br>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="event-type-3" id="etype-3" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-3" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Panel</label> 
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="4" name="event-type-4" id="etype-4" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-4" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Training</label>   
 <br>
<input type="radio" value="5" name="event-type-5" id="etype-5" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-5" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Symposium</label>  
<br>
<input type="radio" value="9" name="event-type-6" id="etype-9" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-9" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Other</label>
<div id="show-me"><TEXTAREA COLS="60" ROWS="4" name="other_item" id="etype-9" maxlength="80" size="25" class="input"></TEXTAREA></div>  

</fieldset>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit1 *').prop( "disabled", true );
  $('#submit1').css('color','#ccc');

  $("input:radio[class^='yes-']").click(function() {
    var no = $(this).parent().attr('id').slice(-1);
    $('#submit'+no+' *').prop( "disabled", false );
    $('#submit'+no+' *').css('color','#000');
  });
  $("input:radio[class^='no-']").click(function() {
    var no = $(this).parent().attr('id').slice(-1);
    $('#submit'+no+' *').prop( "disabled", true );
    $('#submit'+no+' input').prop( "checked", false );
    $('#submit'+no+' textarea').prop( "value", "");
    $('#submit'+no+' *').css('color','#ccc');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Just write a function that takes an id and use that id in your code. For example,

```
var foo = function(id){
    $('#' + id).css('color', '#000');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to using classes then run an `each()` function on them all
With the radio boxes, use `this` then parent and child selectors to find the appropriate elements.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dcfxzb5y/1/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.submit-field *').prop( "disabled", true );
  $('.submit-field ').css('color','#ccc');

  $("input:radio[class^='yes-']").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().children('.submit-field').children().prop( "disabled", false );
      $(this).parent().children('.submit-field').children().css('color','#000');
  });

  $("input:radio[class^='no-']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.submit-field').children().prop( "disabled", true );
    $(this).parent().children('.submit-field').children('input').prop( "checked", false );
    $(this).parent().children('.submit-field').children('textarea').prop( "value", "");
    $(this).parent().children('.submit-field').children().css('color','#ccc');
  });


});
```

HTML:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
  <div class="grps" id="grps1">

   <input type="radio" name="1" class="yes-1" value=1>yes 
   <input type="radio" name="1" class="no-1" value=2>no

  <fieldset class="submit-field">
  <legend>Event Type*</legend>
  <ul>
  <li>Please check event type that best describes your event</li>
  <li>This form must be submitted two weeks prior to event date</li>
  </ul>


  <input type="radio" value="1" name="event-type-1" id="etype-1" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-1" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Meeting</label>   
   <br>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="event-type-2" id="etype-2" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-2" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Seminar</label>  
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="event-type-3" id="etype-3" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-3" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Panel</label> 
   <br>
  <input type="radio" value="4" name="event-type-4" id="etype-4" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-4" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Training</label>   
   <br>
  <input type="radio" value="5" name="event-type-5" id="etype-5" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-5" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Symposium</label>  
  <br>




  <input type="radio" value="9" name="event-type-6" id="etype-9" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-9" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Other</label>
  <div id="show-me"><TEXTAREA COLS="60" ROWS="4" name="other_item" id="etype-9" maxlength="80" size="25" class="input"></TEXTAREA></div>  

  </fieldset>
  </div>

   <BR clear="all">
  <br>


  <div>

   <input type="radio" name="1" class="yes-2" value=1>yes 
   <input type="radio" name="1" class="no-2" value=2>no

  <fieldset class="submit-field">
  <legend>Event Type*</legend>
  <ul>
  <li>Please check event type that best describes your event</li>
  <li>This form must be submitted two weeks prior to event date</li>
  </ul>


  <input type="radio" value="1" name="event-type-1" id="etype-1" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-1" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Meeting</label>   
   <br>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="event-type-2" id="etype-2" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-2" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Seminar</label>  
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="event-type-3" id="etype-3" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-3" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Panel</label> 
   <br>
  <input type="radio" value="4" name="event-type-4" id="etype-4" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-4" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Training</label>   
   <br>
  <input type="radio" value="5" name="event-type-5" id="etype-5" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-5" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Symposium</label>  
  <br>




  <input type="radio" value="9" name="event-type-6" id="etype-9" class="input-float-left"><label for="etype-9" class="label-longer">&nbsp;Other</label>
  <div id="show-me"><TEXTAREA COLS="60" ROWS="4" name="other_item" id="etype-9" maxlength="80" size="25" class="input"></TEXTAREA></div>  

  </fieldset>
  </div>
```